# xbox one stream to linux based pc

Tags: xbox-one

I just want to know if I could stream xbox-one related things onto Linux? I know I can do it in Windows 10 through an app... but I'm just wondering how to.

*Any suggestions appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've found (that I haven't yet tried), is setting up a virtual machine that runs windows 10.  And through that, you know, use the official XBox app.

Wish there were a native way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible to stream directly from Xbox One to Linux directly. As mentioned above, you could stream to a Windows device and then relay that to Linux via some remote desktop/streaming software.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet (don't have enough rep) so this isn't exactly a solution, but I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/gnfko7/found_an_app_that_does_xbox_game_streaming_to/) about `xbox-smartglass-nano`, which does what you're asking. I haven't gotten it to install, though...